# AlertDialog in android 2.1

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, showdialog, android-2.1-eclair

I create and show my dialog in next way:

```
showDialog(1); // Logcat say me that mistake is here.
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
            switch (id) {
            case 1:{
                Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setMessage(R.string.SelectLoc)
                        .setCancelable(true)
                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.Phone, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int which) {
                                        if (mExternalStorageAvailable)
                                        {
                                        PathOpenFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
                                        FileManagerActivity(Settings.Pref.getString("Path_Open", PathOpenFile), REQUEST_LOAD);
                                        }
                                        else 
                                            Toast.makeText(Main.this, R.string.CheckSD , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                })
                        .setNegativeButton(R.string.Ftp, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which){  
                                    if (Settings.Pref.getBoolean("Ftp_User",false))
                                    {
                                        FtpConnect _FtpConnect = new FtpConnect();
                                        _FtpConnect.Save_Open = FTP_REQUEST_LOAD;
                                        _FtpConnect.execute();
                                    }
                                else 
                                Toast.makeText(Main.this, R.string.SetPass , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                });
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
                break;
                }
```

In 2.2 It works very well, but in 2.1 it causes force close with -

> "java.lang.Illegalargumentexeption:
>   Activity#onCreateDialog did not create
>   a dialog for id 1"

Why so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If replace

```
 AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
    break;
```

on

```
return builder.create();
```

It starts work as expected. Dont know why.

Comment: I fixed see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259644/android-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-erron-when-creating-dialog-on-2-1-a/13938677#13938677

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming it is because of [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateDialog%28int%29)

> ```
> protected Dialog onCreateDialog (int id)
>
> Since: API Level 1
> This method is deprecated.
> Old no-arguments version of onCreateDialog(int, Bundle).
> ```

so this line

```
 Protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
```

Should be something like this (untested, but pretty sure)

```
 Protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id, Bundle yourBundle) {
```

Comment: public final boolean showDialog (int id, Bundle args) 
Since: API Level 8 . But I want to use it in API 7. And I dont understand what am I supposed to pass through the bundle?