# Android - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException Erron when creating Dialog on 2.1 and low android

Tags: android, dialog, illegalargumentexception

I'm getting the below error message from phones that are SDK version < 8.  I just released this app on the android market and prior to release my test phones were a HTC Thunderbolt and the Droid X.  Neither had this problem at all.

I'm getting this error report through Flurry.  I'm not able to test this directly because I don't have a phone with SDK < 8  and for some reason I can't get my emulator to start a lower version than the default SDK set for an app.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException, android.app.Activity.createDialog:880 - (Activity#onCreateDialog did not create a dialog for id 1)

Below is the onCreateDialog(int id) that i've implemented.

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    super.onCreateDialog(id);
    Dialog dialog = null;

    switch(id){
    case 1:
        dialog = new CustomCalcDialog(this);
        dialog.setTitle("Enter Shipping %");
        activeTextView = shippingPercent;
        dialog.show();
        dialog = null;
        break;
    case 2:
        dialog = new CustomCalcDialog(this);
        dialog.setTitle("Enter Tax Rate");
        activeTextView = taxPercent;
        dialog.show();
        dialog = null;
        break;
    case 3:
        dialog = new CustomCalcDialog(this);
        dialog.setTitle("Enter Commission %");
        activeTextView = commissionPercent;
        dialog.show();
        dialog = null;
        break;
    case 4:
        dialog = new CustomCalcDialog(this);
        dialog.setTitle("Calculate Subtotal");
        activeTextView = productSubtotal;
        dialog.show();
        dialog = null;
        break;
    case 5:
        dialog = new CustomCalcDialog(this);
        dialog.setTitle("Additional Shipping");
        activeTextView = addShipping;
        dialog.show();
        dialog = null;
        break;
    case 6:
        dialog = new BackgroundOptionsDialog(this);
        dialog.setTitle("Choose Background:");
        dialog.show();
        dialog = null;
        break;
    default:
        dialog = null;
    }
    return dialog;
}
```

And below is how the Dialog is being dismissed.

```
private void registerListeners () {

        enterTotal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    calcLogic(EQUALS);
                }catch(Exception ex){}
                operatorChange = DONT_CHANGE;

                activeTextView.setText(calcDialogDisplay.getText().toString());

                try {
                    if ((Float.parseFloat(calcDialogDisplay.getText().toString())) < 0) {}
                }catch(Exception ex) {
                    activeTextView.setText("0");
                }
                mathCalculations();
                CustomCalcDialog.this.dismiss();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the problem also and solved it with the following:

-Don't return a null Dialog in method: protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)

In Android 2.1 in Activity.java the error was raised on line 871.

```
private Dialog createDialog(Integer dialogId, Bundle state) {
869         final Dialog dialog = onCreateDialog(dialogId);
870         if (dialog == null) {
871             throw new IllegalArgumentException("Activity#onCreateDialog did "
872                     + "not create a dialog for id " + dialogId);
873         }
874         dialog.dispatchOnCreate(state);
875         return dialog;
876     }
```

If you look in later Android there is a check for a null Dialog and it's handeld with a return. So here it works.

-Don't use Bundle (changed in API8):

protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id, Bundle bundle);

use:

protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id);

-I also used the following check (had a special case with a custom dialog):

```
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR_MR1) {
        return dialog;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
```

Maybe it helps someone...

Answer (score 2):

Ah, look at your code:

```
dialog = new CustomCalcDialog(this);
        dialog.setTitle("Enter Shipping %");
        activeTextView = shippingPercent;
        dialog.show();
        dialog = null;
        break;
```

You set `dialog` to null: that's why you are getting the error. Do this:

```
dialog = new CustomCalcDialog(this);
        dialog.setTitle("Enter Shipping %");
        activeTextView = shippingPercent;
        break;
```

Comment: When I first wrote this code I did it like you said and I was getting alot of weird result with the activeTextView getting all messed up.  So I added in the dialog = null.  and it fixed the prodblem.  Is there a way that I can keep the null, but not return a dialog that is null?

Comment: You can return null successfully if you use what I suggest in my answer.  The issue is that if you return null, no dialog will be created.

Comment: In your example you don't have dialog.show();  was that on purpose?

Comment: Yes: once you return a non-null dialog in `onCreateDialog` the dialog will be automatically shown for you. Not sure why you had issues with your activeTextView, though, but this works reliably for me in multiple apps on every version from 2.0 onwards.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the easiest way to deal with this pesky exception is to just catch it:

```
@Override
public void showDialog(int dialogId) {
  try {
    super.showDialog(dialogId);
  } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) { /* Log it if you wish*/ }
}
```

That said, I don't think you're using `onCreateDialog()` as the API intended (which is why you were seeing the strange behavior), it should definitely return a dialog object *most* of the time.

Comment: would I only need to put the try/catch around the super.showDialog or around all of the guts of of the method?

Comment: Only the super, putting one around the guts of the `onCreateDialog()` wouldn't really help you since the exception is not thrown there.

Comment: I figured out why i was getting the strange behaviour and successfully got rid of the null.  I ended up moving the activeTextView to onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog).  This allowed me to not  need the dialog=null.  so a long story short It is working perfect not.

Comment: Good to hear you figured it out! :)

Comment: @dmon, where should this be placed?  When I add it to an activity, Eclipse flags it as `Cannot override the final method from Activity`

Answer (score 1):

I ended up having to get rid of the dialog = null.  I also had to move the switching between activeTextView from onCreateDialog(int id) to onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog).

Below is the updated code.

```
    @Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    super.onCreateDialog(id);
    Dialog dialog = null;

    switch(id){
    case 1:
        dialog = new CustomCalcDialog(this);
        dialog.setTitle("Enter Shipping %");
        break;
    case 2:
        dialog = new CustomCalcDialog(this);
        dialog.setTitle("Enter Tax Rate");
        break;
    case 3:
        dialog = new CustomCalcDialog(this);
        dialog.setTitle("Enter Commission %");
        break;
    case 4:
        dialog = new CustomCalcDialog(this);
        dialog.setTitle("Calculate Subtotal");
        break;
    case 5:
        dialog = new CustomCalcDialog(this);
        dialog.setTitle("Additional Shipping");
        break;
    case 6:
        dialog = new BackgroundOptionsDialog(this);
        dialog.setTitle("Choose Background:");
        break;
    }
    return dialog;
}

@Override
protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
    super.onPrepareDialog(id, dialog);

    switch(id){
    case 1:         
        activeTextView = shippingPercent;
        break;
    case 2:
        activeTextView = taxPercent;
        break;
    case 3:
        activeTextView = commissionPercent;
        break;
    case 4:
        activeTextView = productSubtotal;
        break;
    case 5:
        activeTextView = addShipping;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are returning null from your [`onCreateDialog(int id)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateDialog%28int%29) method (this method is deprecated).

Instead use [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateDialog%28int,%20android.os.Bundle%29).

Comment: If I use onCreateDialog(int, Bundle) will it still be compatible with 2.1 and low?

Comment: @KevinM Probably not, since 2.1 and before don't have this call.